# Nautilus doesn't display contents of the home folder when launched as root

Tags: nautilus, root, home-directory, folder

It shows the desktop symbol but it doesn't show the files on my desktop neither. I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with GNOME shell.

Comment: Just to doublecheck: I assume you're logging in as root, not launching nautilus with a command like `sudo nautilus`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running nautilus in as root, you'll see root's Desktop folder. Yours is likely in `/home/yourname/Desktop` (and the rest of your files are probably elsewhere in `/home/yourname/`)

You can use symlinks to make them available, but operating at root is usually not a good idea. Better to use `sudo` to run commands as root while logged in as your regular old user self.

In nautilus you can use `go > location ...` or `ctrl-l` to view and change the full path to the directory you're in. So do `ctrl l` and then just type in `/home/yourname/Desktop` to access the files in your own user desktop directory.

Comment: I need to copy a file into a folder. I order to make changes to the folder I need to launch nautilus as root which I did with "gksudo nautilus". BUT I can't access the folder where the file is located because it's not displayed anymore.

Comment: @user34648 added to my answer, but you can also use `sudo cp /home/yourname/desktop/file /path/to/destination/` as a command line alternative. Read `man cp` first, though.

Comment: Or use `gksu nautilus ~user_name`

Comment: OK I guess I didn't know that my home folder is not in the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you launch as root you are in root's /home not your's.